# Changing variables for first, second and third derivatives in case of multiple variables

Tags: derivatives, transformation, chain-rule

I spent a few days calculating the first three derivatives of a very nasty function of the form

$f(n_a,n_b, \tau_a,\tau_b, \nabla n_t)$

where $n_t=n_a+n_b$ in $\nabla n_t$.

I need this derivative for part of a code that I am writing for my work and now it turns out I need to transform all the derivatives that I have to derivatives in terms of $n_t$, $n_s=n_a-n_b$, $\tau_t=\tau_a+\tau_b$, $\tau_s=\tau_a-\tau_b$ and $(\nabla n_t)^2$, i.e. the first three derivatives of

$f(n_t, n_s, (\nabla n_t)^2, \tau_t, \tau_s)$.

The conversion for $n_t,n_s$ and $\tau_t,\tau_s$ should be analogous. I know that I need to apply the chain rule but the point where I'm lost is that all of them depend on two variables ($a and b$).

For instance:

$\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{dx}{du}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$ for the first derivative

and $\frac{d^2y}{du^2}=\frac{d^2x}{du^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+(\frac{dx}{du})^2\cdot \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for the second derivative conversion.

If I take a look at the first derivative conversion and let $y=f$ and $u=n_t$ and $x=n_a$ then I have:

$\frac{df}{dn_t}=\frac{dn_a}{dn_t}\cdot \frac{df}{dn_a}$.

I can express $n_\uparrow$ as $n_\uparrow=\frac{1}{2}(n_t+n_s)$ and thus $\frac{dn_\uparrow}{dn_t}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Since I already know $\frac{df}{dn_a}$ that would give me:
$\frac{df}{dn_t}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{df}{dn_a}$

But I can do the same for $n_b$ and would get the same result. I know this is wrong, so I guess my question is how do I the derivatives conversion when there is more than one variable involved?

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I found that for two variables the chain rule is as follows:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

which is simple enough for $n_a,n_b,\tau_a$ and $\tau_b$. And since $\nabla n_t=\sqrt{(\nabla n_t)^2}$ that would give me:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial (\nabla n_t)^2}=\frac{\partial \nabla n_t}{\partial (\nabla n_t)^2}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \nabla n_t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nabla n_t}\cdot \frac{1}{2\nabla n_t}$?

Comment: What does the arrow before or after a letter mean ? Is $n \uparrow$ a variable and $n\downarrow $ another independent variable ?  if so, why don't help us a bit and call the independent variables something like $x,y,z\cdots$

Comment: @Medo Yes, they are all independent variables. I changed the arrows into $a$ and $b$. Maybe that's a bit more clear. Also, I think I did the first derivative conversion and will put that into the edit in a bit.

Comment: If my edit is correct then I think I managed to find what I was looking for.

Comment: You know that $\nabla n_t$ is a vector ?